# Java: Having trouble printing out this pyramid-like reversed number pattern

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I need to know how to print out the following pattern:

```
5
4 5
3 4 5
2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5
4 5
5
```

Any and all help is appreciated.
What i have so far is this:

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
            { 
                System.out.print(j+" "); 
            } 
             
            System.out.println(); 
        }
     for (int i = num-1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(j+" ");
                }
                 
                System.out.println();
            }
```

and it outputs this:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

So I have the structure of the pattern itself understood, but it seems that I need to reverse the flow somehow. This is what I do not understand.

Comment: What happens if you do a little math, instead of outputting loop counters directly? E.g. `print((j+5-i)+" ");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the loop conditions as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 5;
        for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--) {// Start with num and go downwards up to 1
            for (int j = i; j <= num; j++) {// Start with i and go upwards up to num
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {// Start with 2 and go downwards up to num
            for (int j = i; j <= num; j++) {// Start with i and go downwards up to num
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5 
4 5 
3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 
4 5 
5
```

Comment: Those comments help a lot. You're an absolute life-saver, my friend. Thank you.

Comment: @Lev1athan909 - You are most welcome. Wish you success!

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer not output the corrent pattern so... this code works.

Ther are two loops, each one iterate line by line. First from 5 to 1, the second one from 2 to 5.

In every iteration (every line) will print next to the first number the following numbers.

```java
int num = 5;
for(int i = num ; i > 0 ; i--){
    System.out.print(i+" "); //Print the first number of the line
    for(int j = 1; j <= num-i; j++){
    //Print as extra number as line need (first line = 0 extra numbers, 
    //second line = 1 extra number...)
        System.out.print((i+j)+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();  //New line
}
for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) { //Print second part starting by 2
    for (int j = i; j <= num; j++) { //Print extra numbers
        System.out.print(j+" ");
    }
    System.out.println(); //New line
}
```

And the output is as expected:

```
5 
4 5 
3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 
4 5 
5
```